# Calculate CRC32 using owa_opt_lock.checksum

Tags: c#, oracle, hash, checksum, crc

I want to use CRC32 in Oracle DB.
For example,

```
Select id, CRC32(name||age) from students
```

I found the `checksum` function in the package `owa_opt_lock`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15896/pslock.htm#i1005608) it uses `a "pure" 32-bit checksum executed by the database and based on the Internet 1 protocol`, but I can't manage my C# code to get the same results as the database (I think they use a different polynomial to their checksum).

I need to be able to calculate this checksum without access to the database itself.

What is the checksum mechanism Oracle is using?
Is there any *natural* CRC function in Oracle?
Or a different 16/32 bit hash function (no need to be secure and used for encryption) that returns a `NUMBER` that is available out of the box in oracle?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a blog that lists some crc functions.  http://vbegun.blogspot.com/2005/11/plsql-implementation-of-crc32.html  There is a lot of talk around using the ora_hash, or the dbms_crypto.hash function in creating one.

Comment: @Mike the link for the plsql code itself there is broken. I asked to re-upload it but I this post was written in 2005 so I doubt the author will see it...
Unfortunately `dbms_crypto.hash` doesn't fit what I'm trying to achieve since it hash'es to string, I need number. `ora_hash` doesn't fit because I don't think I can mimic it's functionality in C#..

Comment: Can I suggest that you rename your question? I suggest something like "Calculating CRC32 in Oracle"...   The existing title would be meaningless to most people looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: @AnthonyVO will do :)